# How to compare 2 dates in 2 different columns of a csv to tell if the date in column 1 comes before column 2

Tags: python, csv, date, command-line, compare

I'm trying to compare 2 columns of timestamps in a CSV file, and I only want to keep the rows where the date/time in column 1 is before the date/time in column 2. I'm not too sure where to start, since we're looking at comparing many different numbers (e.g. month, year, hour, minute, etc.) separately in relation with one another, including the AM/PM comparison.

Example: (date is [mm/dd/yyyy] format)

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 11/20/2018 3:00:13 PM | 11/23/2017 6:45:00 AM |
| 12/22/2019 4:00:12 PM | 1/10/2020 4:50:11 AM |
| 10/10/2018 2:02:19 PM | 10/07/2018 1:04:15 PM |

Here I would want to keep row 2 because the date in column 2 comes after the date in column 1, and I would not want to keep rows 1 & 3. Is there a neat way to do this in command line? (If not, any pointers to write a Python script would be very helpful)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any specific language that you want to use for this? Is Ruby OK for you?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby, if it's not possible to do it in command line then I'm most comfortable with Python!

Comment: If your CSV __doesn't__ include any quoted data (ex: for escaping commas) then you can parse it directly with the Shell, but it's easier to use a language that has a CSV parser like Perl, Python or Ruby; further processing will also be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you just need to convert each of the date values into `datetime` objects. They can then be easily compared with a simple `<` operator. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    #header = next(csv_input)   
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    #csv_output.writerow(header)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        date_col1 = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        date_col2 = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        
        if date_col1 < date_col2:
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

If your CSV file contains a header, uncomment the two lines. You can find more information on how the format string work with the [`.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) function documentation.

This approach uses built in Python functionality and so does not need further modules to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

I will try and keep this as clear and detailed as possible so everyone can understand :

**1) First I imported python's datetime library**

```
import datetime as dt
```

**2) Now i am importing the csv file which i have to work on , in this case I have used *dates.csv* which has the same data as in the question asked above :**

```
from csv import reader
dataset = list(reader(open("dates.csv", encoding = "utf-8")))
```

**2.1) Printing dataset to check if its working :**

```
dataset
```

[image]

***printing a single date from our dataset in order to check pattern :***

> Keep in mind that indexing in python starts with zero

```
dataset[1][0] # dataset[row][column]
```

[image]

**2.2) Pattern is *month/day/year hour:min:sec AM/PM***

```
pattern = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
```

you can check [Legal Format Codes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_date_format_codes.asp) in order to create a different pattern in future.

**3) Now converting our dataset dates into date time object using the library we imported**

```
    for i in dataset[1:]: 
# [1:] because 1st row has heading and we don't need it

        i[0] = dt.datetime.strptime(i[0],pattern)
        i[1] = dt.datetime.strptime(i[1],pattern)

    print(dataset[1][0])
```

[image]

***successfully converted ^***

**4) Now we will manually comparing dates in order to understand the concepts.**

> by simply using comparison operators we can compare the dates in python
> using datetime library

```
print(dataset[2][0] , "and" , dataset[2][1])
print(dataset[2][0] > dataset[2][1])
```

[image]

**5) Now creating a separate list in which only those rows will be added where column 2's date is greater than column 1's date :**

```
col2_greatorthan_col1 = []
```

***adding heading in our new list :***

```
col2_greatorthan_col1.append(["column 1" , "column 2"])
```

***comparing each and every date and appending our desired row in our new list :***

```
for i in dataset[1:]:
    if i[1] > i[0]: # means if column 2's date is greater than column 1's date
        col2_greatorthan_col1.append(i) # appending the filtered rows in our new list

col2_greatorthan_col1
```

[image]

**6) Now simply creating a real world csv file which will have the same data as *col2_greatorthan_col1***

```
import csv

with open("new_dates.csv" , "w" , newline = "") as file :
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

### Result :

A new csv file by the name of **new_dates.csv** will be created in the same directory as your python code file.
This file will only contain those rows where column 2's date is greater than column 1's date.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you're slurping all the CSV into memory, which has some caveats. BTW, great explanations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With comman line tools you can use `awk`:
to convert 1st date to epoch format:

```
echo "11/20/2018 3:00:13 PM" |gawk -F'[/:]' '{print mktime($3" "$1" "$2" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7)}'
```

same for the second field. And then subtract column 2 from column 1. If the result is positive this mean column 1 is after column 2
Here is used function `mktime` from `awk` which do the "magic". Be aware this function is not available in some of UNIX `awk` version

Comment: I don't know how it happened but I downvoted your reply; please edit your post so that I can undo it

Comment: @Fravadona, feel free to undo it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Read tab delimited CSV file without header
# Names columns date1, date2
df = pd.read_csv("dates.csv", 
                  header = None,
                  sep='\t', 
                  parse_dates = [0, 1],        # use default date parser i.e. parser.parser
                  names=["date1", "date2"])

# Filter (keep) row when date2 > date1
df = df[df.date2 > df.date1]

# Output to filtered CSV file using the original date format
df.to_csv('filtered_dates.csv', index = False, header = False, sep = '\t', date_format  = "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have saved the sample you provided in a tab separated file - with no headers. I have imported it as a `DataFrame` using (note that I specified your date format in `date_parser`):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE, sep="\t", names=["col1", "col2"], parse_dates=[0,1], date_parser=lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

To select the rows you need:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,"col2"]>df.loc[:,"col1"],:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` to parse the date-time strings and then use their comparison as a condition to filter the required rows.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start': ['11/20/2018 3:00:13 PM', '12/22/2019 4:00:12 PM', '10/10/2018 2:02:19 PM'],
    'end': ['11/23/2017 6:45:00 AM', '1/10/2020 4:50:11 AM', '10/07/2018 1:04:15 PM']
})

result = pd.DataFrame(df[
                pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') <
                pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
            ])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
                   start                   end
1  12/22/2019 4:00:12 PM  1/10/2020 4:50:11 AM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/s2jJxv)